# complex number limit question

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that $$\lim \limits_{z\rightarrow \infty} {\frac{z^4+16}{z^5-16}}=0$$

We weren't given a definition for when the variable approaches infinity. I was trying to manipulate it and I got $$\frac{1+\frac{16}{z^4}}{z-\frac{16}{z^4}}$$ but can we take the limit now? Would it be sufficiently rigorous?

Comment: Yes it would, as long as you already know/can prove that $\;\frac1{z^k}\to 0\;$ , with natural $\;k\;$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide top and bottom by $z^5$ instead of $z^4$. The quotient will be $$\frac{\frac{1}{z} + \frac{16}{z^5}}{1 - \frac{16}{z^5}}$$ whose limit is now computable. Let $f(z)$ be the above expression be. We can compute $\lim_{z\to \infty} f(z)$ by calculating $\lim_{z\to 0} f(1/z)$; we have $$\lim_{z\to 0} f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right) = \lim_{z\to 0} \frac{z + 16z^5}{1 - 16z^5} = \frac{0 + 0}{1 - 0} = 0$$

Comment: Beat me to it,darn................